# Issue with a class method

Tags: python, class, methods

I have to create a class Color of this type

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b
```

and i have to create these methods:

-createatuple() that returns a tuple (r, g, b) of the object's color

-mixture(f) that returns a new instance of the color and its values are a mixture of the current instance with the color f

I tried this

```
>>>class Color:
       def __init__(self, r, g, b):
           self.r = r
           self.g = g
           self.b = b
       def createatuple(self):
           return (self.r, self.g, self.b)
       def mixture(self, f):
           self.r = int((self.r+f.r)/2)
           self.g = int((self.g+f.g)/2)
           self.b = int((self.b+f.b)/2)
           return self.r
           return self.g
           return self.b

>>>color1 = Color(10,15,10)
>>>color1.createatuple()
(10,15,10)
>>>color2 = Color(20,5,200)
>>>color2.createatuple()
(20,5,200)
```

If i wanna do:

```
>>>color1.mixture(color2).createatuple()
(15,10,105)
```

But i receive " 'str' object has no attribute 'createatuple()' "

What's wrong?

Comment: The output you'll get from that is (10, 15, 10)
(20, 5, 200).is that the desired output?

Comment: In `mixture`: (1) Why would you assign attributes to the color? You're making a new color, not changing the current one. (2) Why are you returning numbers instead of an instance of `Color`? (3) You can't return three times. Once you return once the function ends.

Comment: Side-note: You're referring to instance methods, not class methods. Class methods do things not connected to instances, so they wouldn't be able to read instance attributes from `self` (the first argument to an `@classmethod` is `cls`, the class itself, not an instance of the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mixture` method isn't making a new instance. And it's returning just the `self.r` value (multiple uses of `return` don't do anything; the first one ends the method). I see no way you made a `str` though; there are no `str`s in your example code. Presumably, you want something like this for `mixture`:

```
def mixture(self, f):
    # For subclassing friendliness, you might construct via:
    # type(self)(...) instead of Color(...)
    return Color((self.r + f.r) // 2, (self.g + f.g) // 2, (self.b + f.b) // 2)
```

Comment: Note: I used `//` instead of `/` which removes the need for wrapping in `int`; `//` is floor division (for positive `int`s, it behaves like C division, truncating).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what `mixture` should do, but anyway, you have 3 `return` statements inside it. Note that a line that starts with `return` ends the entire method, returning the value.

So, in your case, you are always returning `self.r`, which means that, in practice, you are doing `self.r.createtuple()`. However, `self.r` obviously does not have this method, as it's not a `Color`.